# Lock the item in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

We have upgraded from Sitecore 6.6 to Sitecore 8.2

We are getting a weird issue when user opens a page in the `Experience Editor` and locks page to edit it. We expected to get edit options but we are not getting them until we refresh the page.

It is happening on all the pages.

Sitecore Version : Sitecore.NET 8.2 Update 5 (rev. 170728)

Checked Console, I found following errors :

[image]

Comment: Can you see if you have any errors in the network tab or console tab from inspect element or logs

Comment: I think the main problem here is with XMLHttpRequest and XHR headers that Chrome from certain version don't like. Can you try to do the same in Firefox? Can you try to upgrade to latest 8.2 version Update 7? You are using Update 5 which could be not so nicely compatible with newest versions of Chrome because of XHR.